# How to post x-editable input value on razor page

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, x-editable

I want when click to submit button,
send form to post method.
thanks for your help.

html code

```
                                <form method="post" class="form-horizontal editor-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <a href="#" id="name" data-type="text"
                                               data-pk="1" data-placeholder="Required"
                                               data-title="نام خود را وارد کنید">@Model.Information.Doctor.Name</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">نام</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <a data-pk="1" data-placeholder="Required" data-placement="left"
                                               data-title="نام خانوادگی خود را وارد کنید " data-type="text"
                                               href="#" id="family" >@Model.Information.Doctor.Family</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">نام خانوادگی </label>
                                    </div>
                           
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  >تایید</button>/>
                             </form>
```

this is my method post

```
        public IActionResult OnPost(EditDoctorViewModel command)
        {
           var user= _service.EditDoctor(command);

           return Page();

        }
```

Comment: why you use `<a>...</a>` in your view ? if you want to pass value to Post method,you should use `<input></input>`@Qudrat Ihsas

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send form to post method, you should use `input` in your view, Here is my code:

**model**

```
public class EditDoctorViewModel
    {
        public Information information { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
public class Information
    {
        public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
public class Doctor
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Family { get; set; }
    }
```

**veiw**

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal editor-horizontal">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" >نام</label>
       <input type="text" asp-for="command.information.Doctor.Name" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">                             
         <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" >نام خانوادگی </label>
         <input type="text" asp-for="command.information.Doctor.Family" />
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">تایید</button>
</form>
```

**controller**

```
        public EditDoctorViewModel command { get; set; }
        public Information Information { get; set; }
 

        public IActionResult OnPost([FromForm]EditDoctorViewModel command)
        {
            //var user = _service.EditDoctor(command);

            return Page();

        }
```

**Then you can receive value in Post Method.**
[image]